# How to view console log of XCode inside app iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, console

We can see the debug log in XCode.
Does it possible to view the console log inside the iOS App?
I viewed some apps have this feature. How to make it?
[image]

Comment: Most likely, those Apps have implemented their own logging workflow, one part of which will print to the console, [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack) is an example

Comment: Having said that, Apple recommends make use of the [OSLog](https://www.avanderlee.com/debugging/oslog-unified-logging/) workflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about Flex? https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX 
FLEX (Flipboard Explorer) is a set of in-app debugging and exploration tools for iOS development. When presented, FLEX shows a toolbar that lives in a window above your application. From this toolbar, you can view and modify nearly every piece of state in your running application.

[image]

Give Yourself Debugging Superpowers

1. Inspect and modify views in the hierarchy.
2. See the properties and ivars on any object.
3. Dynamically modify many properties and ivars.
4. Dynamically call instance and class methods.
5. Observe detailed network request history with timing, headers, and full responses.
6. Add your own simulator keyboard shortcuts.
7. View system log messages (e.g. from NSLog).
8. Access any live object via a scan of the heap.
9. View the file system within your app's sandbox.
10. Browse SQLite/Realm databases in the file system.
11. Trigger 3D touch in the simulator using the control, shift, and command keys.
12. Explore all classes in your app and linked systems frameworks (public and private).
13. Quickly access useful objects such as [UIApplication sharedApplication], the app delegate, the root view controller on the key window, and more.
14. Dynamically view and modify NSUserDefaults values.

    Unlike many other debugging tools, FLEX runs entirely inside your app, so you don't need to be connected to LLDB/Xcode or a different remote debugging server. It works well in the simulator and on physical devices.

Comment: `FLEX` is pretty good but should be removed in the AppStore build as it will be rejected.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved something like this recently in one of my apps. What I did was overwrite the `print` method, and added it to a `UITextView` I had in my app.

Looks something like this:

```swift
func print(_ items: Any...) {
    //Add `items` to a text view here
    Swift.print(items)
}
```